# After hibernation, USB SSD shows under "remove safely" but not in file explorer - until reboot

Tags: windows-10, external-hard-drive, usb-storage, samsung-ssd

Usage scenario:

1. Arrive at work, wake PC from hibernate-to-disk, plug in my WD Elements USB SSD.
2. See it's not shown in file explorer nor disk management, but it does show up in the systray USB icon under "remove safely" (which doesn't appear to do anything in that state).
3. Reboot the Win10 machine. It finds the drive, and it functions as expected.
4. Evening: "Safely remove" the drive, unplug, send Windows to hibernation.

Next morning: rinse & repeat ...
Every single time... Whether I use the front USB bay jacks, or the rear mainboard jacks.
It isn't that fussy with some regular old USB stick, although I have had the occasional case of "won't accept any newly plugged-in USB stick until reboot" every couple months or so, but that's probably true of every win7/win10 machine I ever used. No other device is in the front USB hub when I connect that (which could e.g. draw power), and they are USB3 ports.

DISKPART doesn't show the drive. It does always show all the "no media" drives that the card reader bay, connected to one USB connector on the mainboard, provides (which also always are in Explorer).

The SSD itself is fine, and the usual answers on all the tech help sites are uncalled for, e.g. partition the drive, format it, etc...
The drive is detected on other computers - and, as said, also this one, after a reboot.
It's just a tad inconvenient to not realistically be able to use the OS'es hibernation function when the drive makes me reboot anyway.

What's a likely cause of this?

**EDIT**: The odd behavior, that I can't properly (un)mount the disk anymore, only starts once VirtualBox has been running once after boot. VirtualBox has a VM on that drive. But I don't even need to start the VM, only the Manager. Closing it again does not help.

Comment: What about hibernating while the device is plugged-in, then plugging it in before waking?

Comment: This ^^^ is exactly what I do, always. Never had a problem following the accepted correct practices.

Comment: Yes I thought about that - which is a pragmatic HACK. An actual fix would be nice, that prevents e.g. requiring a restart due to accidentally not following this "oh better don't touch a thing when using Windows, it's so fragile".
@ChanganAuto: the "accepted correct practises" _are_ to "safeley remove". But that's what doesn't work here.

Comment: Btw., doing it that way - removing the USB drive when the PC is in hibernation, and also pluggin it in again _before_ switching it on again, yields a very strange effect I don't know what to make of. Thought I erred at first, but now it's repeated: I copy a file onto the USB drive at home, unmount properly, mount again & check file is still there - yep. Then I do the described procedure with the hibernating PC at work - and the file isn't there. When I'm home again, the file isn't there anymore either. Now what the heck is going on there? Nothing short of bizarre.